# `ggplot2` legend not showing label for added series

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following `ggplot2` with two series, US GDP and its moving average, the legend doesn't display the moving average series:

```
require(xts);require(data.table);require(ggplot2);require(ggthemes)

# US GDP quarterly data
data <- structure(list(ShortName = c("US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)","US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)",  "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)",  "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)","US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)",  "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)","US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)", "US GDP QoQ (Annualised)"), Date = structure(c(10681L, 10772L,10864L, 10956L, 11047L, 11138L, 11230L, 11322L, 11412L, 11503L,11595L, 11687L, 11777L, 11868L, 11960L, 12052L, 12142L, 12233L,12325L, 12417L, 12508L, 12599L, 12691L, 12783L, 12873L, 12964L,13056L, 13148L, 13238L, 13329L, 13421L, 13513L, 13603L, 13694L,13786L, 13878L, 13969L, 14060L, 14152L, 14244L, 14334L, 14425L,14517L, 14609L, 14699L, 14790L, 14882L, 14974L, 15064L, 15155L,15247L, 15339L, 15430L, 15521L, 15613L, 15705L, 15795L, 15886L,15978L, 16070L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), Value = c(3.8,3.4, 5.2, 7.1, 1.2, 7.8, 0.5, 2.1, -1.1, 2.1, -1.2, 1, 3.8, 2.2,1.9, 0.2, 2, 3.8, 6.9, 4.6, 2.4, 3.1, 3.6, 3.4, 4.5, 2.2, 3.3,2.2, 4.9, 1.3, 0.3, 3.2, 0.3, 3.1, 2.7, 1.5, -2.7, 2, -2, -8.3,-5.4, -0.4, 1.3, 3.9, 1.6, 3.9, 2.8, 2.8, -1.3, 3.2, 1.4, 4.9,3.7, 1.2, 2.8, 0.1, 1.1, 2.5, 4.1, 2.4)), .Names = c("ShortName","Date", "Value"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-60L))

ggplot(data, aes_string(x="Date", y="Value", colour="ShortName")) + 
  geom_line(size=1.2) +

  # add 4 quarter moving average series
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, 
                y=rollmean(Value, k=4, fill=NA, align="right"))
            , colour="red") +

  # the economist theme from package::ggthemes
  theme_economist_white(gray_bg=FALSE) + 
  scale_colour_economist() +
  xlab("") + ylab("")
```

***Question:*** How to add the moving average series label to the legend, (text saying let's say "4-quarters moving avg"?

***Bonus question:*** How to remove `ShortName` text from the legend?

Comment: You should map it to geom_line aesthetics

Comment: You have two entries for [ShortNames] but I suppose it is a mistyping (extra spaces).

Comment: edited, but not material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe specifying something to aesthetics

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_line(aes_string(x="Date", y="Value", colour="ShortName"), size=1.2) +
  # add 4 quarter moving average series
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, 
                y=rollmean(Value, k=4, fill=NA, align="right"),
                linetype =  'Moving average'),
            colour="red") +
  scale_colour_manual('', values = "blue") +
  scale_linetype_manual('', values = 1)
```

and with ggthemes

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_line(aes_string(x="Date", y="Value", colour="ShortName"), size=1.2) +
  # add 4 quarter moving average series
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, 
                y=rollmean(Value, k=4, fill=NA, align="right"),
                linetype =  'Moving average'),
            colour="red") +
  scale_colour_economist(name='') +
  #scale_colour_manual('', values = "blue") +
  scale_linetype_manual('', values = 1) +
  theme_economist_white(gray_bg=FALSE)
```

[image: ggtheme plot]

You may change the order of legend items with

```
plot <- ggplot(data) + 
  geom_line(aes_string(x="Date", y="Value", colour="ShortName"), size=1.2) +
  # add 4 quarter moving average series
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, 
                y=rollmean(Value, k=4, fill=NA, align="right"),
                linetype =  'Moving average'),
            colour="red") +
  scale_colour_economist(name='') +
  #scale_colour_manual('', values = "blue") +
  scale_linetype_manual('', values = 1) +
  theme_economist_white(gray_bg=FALSE)

plot + guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1), 
              linetype = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image: change legend order]

Comment: Can this be made compatible with The Economist theme (a must have)? Thanks for some pointers, I will fiddle some more

Comment: @DanielKrizian Let me tell you that `rollmean` is completely new for me. Thanks!

Comment: excellent, we both learn! I understand that you added second series (moving average) as linetype, having own linetype legend, whereas the first series has colour legend (the only available in The Economist theme). So the two series have two separate legends, complicating the code a little bit