# Can't add legend panel to a certain scatter plot with multiple data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I simply can't find a way to plot legends panel in this specific ggplot with ggplot2 on R. Just want to make it appear.

For context, I'm plotting chemical abundances of sample versus the atomic number of the elements.

For background, I tried many things that are described here:

[Reasons that ggplot2 legend does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768567/reasons-that-ggplot2-legend-does-not-appear?rq=1)

including links therein, however could not find a solution for my specific data set.

I know the problem could be within the structure of the data set, since I've been able to do that with other data, but I can't solve it. I also know that the problem should have to do with the theme() described in the code below, because when I use default ggplot configuration legends actually appear. I use this personalized theme for consistency trough out my work.

This is what I have so far removing cosmetics:

```
ggplot(atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y = atomic$avg, group=1), fill = atomic$Z) +
```

## plot dots for average of values

```
geom_point(data=atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y=atomic$avg, group=1, color="black"), size=0.5, alpha=1, shape=16 ) +
```

## connect dots for average of values

```
geom_line(data=atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y=atomic$avg, group=1), color="black", linetype= "dashed") +
```

## plot dots for actual values from the samples

```
geom_point(data=atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y=atomic$SDSS, group=1, color="#00ba38"), size=5, alpha=1, shape=16, color="#00ba38") +

geom_point(data=atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y=atomic$HE22, group=1, color="#619cff"), size=5, alpha=1, shape=16, color="#619cff") +

geom_point(data=atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y=atomic$HE12, group=1, color="#F8766D"), size=5, alpha=1, shape=16, color="#F8766D") +
```

## EDIT: the Definition of base_breaks (used below)

```
base_breaks_x <- function(x){
  b <- pretty(x)
  d <- data.frame(y=-Inf, yend=-Inf, x=min(b), xend=max(b))
  list(geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes=FALSE),
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=b))
}
base_breaks_y <- function(x){
  b <- pretty(x)
  d <- data.frame(x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=min(b), yend=max(b))
  list(geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes=FALSE),
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=b))
}
```

## the problem might be here

```
theme_bw() +

theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    text = element_text(size=20),
    legend.position="bottom",
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
base_breaks_x(atomic$Z) +
base_breaks_y(atomic$HE22)
```

## The data set is the following

```
 Z Name  HE22  SDSS  HE12   avg
1   3   Li    NA  1.00    NA  1.00        
2   6    C  6.16  5.50  6.06  5.91              
3   7    N    NA    NA  6.49  6.49           
4  11   Na    NA    NA  3.53  3.53         
5  12   Mg  5.32  4.43  4.99  4.91         
6  13   Al  2.90    NA  3.08  2.99           
7  14   Si    NA  4.90  4.89  4.90              
8  20   Ca  4.07  3.37  3.56  3.67             
9  21   Sc  0.72 -0.07  0.24  0.30            
10 22   Ti  2.74  1.79  2.47  2.33             
11 23    V    NA    NA  1.18  1.18            
12 24   Cr  2.88  2.14  2.67  2.56              
13 25   Mn  2.34  1.59  2.44  2.12        
14 26   Fe  4.92  4.14  4.59  4.55           
15 27   Co  2.57  1.72  2.36  2.22           
16 28   Ni  3.63  2.96  3.51  3.37               
17 29   Cu    NA    NA  0.31  0.31              
18 30   Zn  2.29    NA  2.44  2.37           
19 38   Sr  0.62  0.29  0.41  0.44           
20 39    Y -0.22 -0.44 -0.33 -0.33             
21 40   Zr  0.60    NA  0.30  0.45             
22 56   Ba  0.13 -0.10  0.12  0.05            
23 57   La -0.77 -0.49 -0.77 -0.68         
24 58   Ce    NA    NA -0.39 -0.39            
25 59   Pr    NA    NA -0.78 -0.78               
26 60   Nd -0.47    NA -0.37 -0.42              
27 62   Sm    NA    NA -0.57 -0.57         
28 63   Eu -1.02 -0.92 -0.85 -0.93               
29 64   Gd    NA    NA -0.39 -0.39             
30 66   Dy    NA    NA -0.16 -0.16               
31 68   Er    NA -0.40    NA -0.40               
32 70   Yb    NA -0.60    NA -0.60                
33 90   Th    NA -0.60    NA -0.60
```

as Z = atomic number, Name = element, HE12/HE22/SDSS = samples, avg = average of the samples.

I would like to know how I can add legend panel coherent with the colors of my scatter plots.

Thank you so much! Hope I could describe the problem properly.

Comment: How are you defining `base_breaks_x()` and `base_breaks_y()`?  They are not `ggplot2` functions

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, gonna edit it right away. It was stupid not to have included that in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is personally what I would do.

I converted the data from wide format to long format since it's easier to manipulate colors that way (Sorry I just used generic "key" and "value" since I'm not sure what you would want your columns to be named).  Hopefully this will get you at least part of the way to where you want to go.  Let me know if you have questions!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
p <- atomic %>% 
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", SDSS, HE22, HE12) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Z, value, color = key))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(x = Z, y = avg, label = Name), # EDITED
            color = "black")
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00ba38", "#619cff", "#F8766D"))
p +
  geom_line(data=atomic, aes(x=atomic$Z, y=atomic$avg, group=1), color="black", 
            linetype= "dashed") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        text = element_text(size=20),
        legend.position="bottom",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
base_breaks_x(atomic$Z) +
base_breaks_y(atomic$HE22)
```

**EDITED**

I added the `geom_text()` command so labels show up.  You can adjust the arguments so the labels look better.  I've also heard `geom_text_repel()` in the `ggrepel` package is helpful for creating nice labels: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html#examples
[image: My output]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was, actually, exactly what I was looking for.

Now, what I'm trying to do is adding labels to the plot for each chemical element, like this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/6797DLP) (that's what I had before posting here).

Comment: I edited the code above^.  Basically I just added one command

Comment: Thank you so so much! You actually helped me even more with this implementation. I had stopped working on this project and now I'm back to it with a complete solution from you. I really appreciate it!